# How to build dlib for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, dlib

I'm trying to build dlib for iOS. I have generated a libdlib.a file but when checking with

```
otool -lv libdlib.a | grep LC_VERSION
```

I get:

```
cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
```

How can I build for iOS instead?

Comment: Did you solved it out eventually?

Comment: @RoiMulia Yes, do you need help doing the same?

Comment: Eventually i found a way haha. Wasn't easy tho

Comment: Could you please explain your solution?

Comment: @RioMulia can you answer this question then?

Comment: or @ChristinaTsangouri?